# apiResource with multiple role access

Tags: laravel, routes, roles

I have two roles, admin (which have access on every methods like post, put, delete) and user which have access to only get method. I've created api resource controller which have every methods defined. I can use it like

```
Route::apiResource('measure', 'MeasureTypeController');
```

I have two middleware groups:

```
//admin role routes
Route::middleware('role:admin')->group(function () {
   //...
});

//user role routes
Route::middleware('role:user')->group(function () {
   //...
});
```

admin role can access to routes defined in user role group. But user cannot access to routes defined in admin group.
How I must write my api resource route to prevent access to user to methods delete put and post?

Comment: I think there are two ways you could do this. Either break down the routes one by one and group them in the middleware you specified or create one middleware that will run on resource routes and check if the requester has access to the method?

Comment: @Mozammil If there is no simple solution I have to go with first way. But currently I am read about only mehtod in apiResource. I think I can separate it like 
`Route::apiResource('measure', 'MeasureTypeController')->only([
            'store', 'update', 'destroy'
        ]);`
to admin and only get for user. I am not tried it yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin',  'middleware' => 'role:admin'], function()
{
    Route::apiResource('measure', 'MeasureTypeController');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:user'], function()
{
    Route::apiResource('measure', 'MeasureTypeController')->except(['create','store', 'update', 'destroy' ]);
});
```